# Is it possible to make an only minutes (1m) countdown in a Live Activity?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit, widgetliveactivity, dynamic-island

It's weird because in **documentation** (SwiftUI, Live Activities, Dynamic Island) I keep seeing images like:

[image]

Or even

[image]

And in iPhone clock app (timer):

[image]

But it seems like the only way to make a functional timer is:

```
Text(context.state.startTime, style: .timer)
```

But it's very limited when it comes to formatting.

It has it's own behaviors for example on Stand by mode; it changes to things like: "< 1 minute" or "5 minutes" but on the dynamicIsland limited space its not helping. You end with "2:45:56" when maybe you need "2h"

Is any way to achieve this behavior that we se so often in Docs and videos?

Comment: You are supposed to update the live activity using push notifications. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/starting-and-updating-live-activities-with-activitykit-push-notifications

Comment: I don't think that updating a local timer through a server with push notifications every minute for hours only to show a different format of String is the right solution for me. @Sweeper